# Modding Z[x,y] by a finitely generated ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am studying up for the prelims, and I am trying to remember all the things my professors taught me back before summer XD. So! Whilst doing so, I stumbled across the following:

> This question concerns the polynomial ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[x, y]$ and the ideal
>   $I = (5, x^2 + 2)$ in $R$.
>   (a) Prove that $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$ and that $R/I$ is a PID.
>   (b) Give an explicit example of a maximal ideal of $R$ which contains $I$.
>   (Give a set of generators for such an ideal.)
>   (c) Show that there are infinitely many distinct maximal ideals in $R$ which contain $I$.

So, what I think I should do, and what I consider mild sorcery, is to say that
$\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(5, x^2+2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_5[x,y]/(x^2+2)$.
Now, $x^2 + 2$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and, as such, is irreducible. Thus, $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2 + 2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_5[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a field, and so, we have that $\mathbb{Z}_5[x,y]/(x^2+2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_5[\sqrt{-2}][y]$, which are just polynomials over the field $\mathbb{Z}_5[\sqrt{-2}]$, which is a Euclidean domain, and as such is an Integral Domain, which implies Prime~ness of the Ideal, and is also a PID, proving (a).

So, my question is, are these manipulations valid?!? Haha. If so, can someone explain to me why I can just mod by a single generator of the ideal at a time? I feel it is something that my professor taught me, but I don't see the justification for it.

Additionally, to do parts (b) and (c) I assume you just consider $M = (5, x^2 + 2, f(y))$, where $f(y)$ is an irreducible polynomial in  $\mathbb{Z}_5[\sqrt{-2}]$.

Thanks immensely for all your help in advance! =)

Comment: You could have written $F_{25}$, the field with 25 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rigorous justification of cancellation in stages is the third isomorphism theorem for commutative rings.  Part of it states that for any commutative ring $R$ and any two ideals $I,J$ with $I\subset J$, $$R/J \simeq (R/I)/(J/I).$$  In your case $J = (5,x^2+2)$ and $I=(5)$.

Also, you do not need to invoke Euclidean property at any point. For any field $k$, the polynomial ring in one variable $k[x]$ is an integral domain.

Comment: I invoked the Euclidean Property because I had to show it was also a PID and as a bonus I just said it showed Integral Domain as well.  
For part (c) I need to show that there are infinitely many $M$, but yes for part (b) I could just use $f(y) = y$.  

Thanks!! This is the justification that I was looking for. Thanks! :D

Comment: @Laarz I see, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Laarz I did not notice you needed infinitely many $M$ in part c), making my third point invalid.  I will edit it away.